# Hibernate autocommit true for a single command

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, autocommit

Hibernate automatically sets autocommit to false, and indeed even recommends against setting it to true.

I find myself in the need of having autocommit set to true for a single database command (I want to send 'VACUUM' to my postgresql database, which requires autocommit set to true), but I want autocommit to be set (as recommended) to false for everything else.

I can't seem to find any way to change the autocommit setting programmatically for a single session.

-- Do I need to have a separate Configuration/SessionFactory for this one operation??

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly the VACUUM does for your database? Is this what it does http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html ?

Comment: It's a RedShift database. Very similar to the sqlite link you posted. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Reclaiming_storage_space202.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend leaving autocommit as false, but using a setter for VACUUM and at the end of the setter calling sessionManager.save(this) (assuming you can get a SessionManager handle to that point).  Be sure to have the AccessType for VACUUM be AccessType.FIELD, not AccessType.PROPERTY, or you'll get some unneccesary database queries.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're saying. Could you please elaborate?